# Selecting a subview in a custom UITableViewCell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView comprised of custom UITableViewCells with some text and a button in them.
The cell's allowSelection property is set to NO so that I can tap the button without selecting the cell.

I am trying to find a way to know which cell in the table was tapped when the button for that cell is pressed.  Is there any way to do this???

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this if your `UIButton` is a direct subview of the `UITableViewCell` (`[cell addSubview:button];` or `cell.accessoryView = button;`)

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview;
}
```

Or if your `UIButton` is a subview of the `UITableViewCell`'s `contentView` (`[cell.contentView addSubview:button];`):

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)button.superview.superview;
}
```

Comment: How could this tell me which cell the tapped button was in though? Ie., the 3rd cell in the second section.  Also, my button is a subview of the UITableViewCell's contentView.

Comment: This gives you the cell itself, the `UITableViewCell` object. If you want to know the `indexPath` for this cell, however, you can use `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [someTableView indexPathForCell:cell];`